# Self Transfer flight From Baku to Budapest to Warsawa

Tags: schengen, poland, hungary, budapest, self-transfer

I have a visa for Poland but not for Hungary. And I want to buy a cheap self transfer flight From Baku To Budapest Wizz Air, then wait for 17 hours to get in another Wizz Air flight from Budapest to Warsaw. Do I need transfer visa for that?

I won't have any extra baggage.

Comment: Budapest is in Hungary, not Romania -- I suspect you're confusing it with Bucharest?  The good news is that Poland and Hungary are both in the Schengen Area, so one visa will suffice for both.

Comment: Oh, My bad sorry for the confusion. I fixed it. According to google bulgaria isn't a schegen country. Are schegen country and area different things?

Comment: Wizz Air is a Hungarian airline and based in Budapest, Hungary. In a reasonable itinerary, it would be Azerbaijan → Hungary → Poland. It has nothing to do with Bulgaria nor Romania. You can edit in the airport codes to ease every bit of confusion

Comment: W62500 to arrive Budapest. W62467 to Go Warsaw

Answer (score 9):

Your itinerary involves a self-transfer in Budapest (`BUD`), **Hungary**

Both Poland and Hungary are in the Schengen Area, your visa for Poland will suffice to do that connection

After passing entry passport control, you'll be in the country and free to go in the city